# How to reformat axis labels?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've begun learning D3, and many tutorials are written for v3. I read through a lot of v4's documentation, but I can't wrap my mind around how to format my axis labels. Right now I have a visualization that looks like this:[image: d3 viz]

The months overlapping is not ideal. I know I can use [d3's timeFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md) and use "%b" to use an abbreviated month. But I'm not sure how syntactically it fits in. My code for the bottom axis is:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(4)));
```

I would've expected it to be something like

```
format = d3.time.format("%b")
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(format(d3.timeMonth.every(4))));
```

But that doesn't work. I know this is probably very simple, but I'm not getting it.

Comment: Just a side note: in D3 v4.x it's `d3.timeFormat`, not `d3.time.format`... you should get an error because of that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `tickFormat` instead of `ticks`:

```
.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b"))
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

EDIT: For showing the year instead of January:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([20, 480])
  .domain([new Date(), new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.timeFormat("%b")(d) === "Jan" ?
      d3.timeFormat("%Y")(d) : d3.timeFormat("%b")(d);
  })
  .ticks(d3.timeMonth);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500"></svg>
```

Comment: Yup that works. Is there a way to mix time formats? Ideally I'd like to have the year number ("%Y") at the first month of every year. Is that even possible?